# Como fazer percurso pré-ordem em árvore binária estática C

Tags: c, árvore-binária

Estou implementando uma árvore binária estática ordenada em C, porém através de inserção simples, ou seja, não tenho um método que já insere de forma ordenada. No entanto, estou tendo dificuldade em percorrer essa árvore através do caminhamento pré-ordem. Na impressão, obtenho apenas o valor do primeiro nó. Alguém pode me explicar no que estou errando, por favor?

Segue abaixo o código:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct str_no {
    char dado;
    int esquerda;
    int direita;
    int pai;
} str_no;

#define tamanho 100

struct str_no arvore[tamanho];

void preOrdem(str_no* raiz);

//modficar essa função
void preOrdem(str_no* raiz){
    if(raiz){
        printf("%c \t", raiz->dado);
        preOrdem(raiz-> esquerda);
        preOrdem(raiz-> direita);
    }
}


int main(){
    arvore[0].dado = '2';
    arvore[0].pai = -1;
    arvore[0].esquerda = 1;
    arvore[0].direita = 2;
    
    arvore[1].dado = '1';
    arvore[1].pai = 0;
    arvore[1].esquerda = 3;
    arvore[1].direita = 4;
    
    arvore[2].dado = '6';
    arvore[2].pai = 0;
    arvore[2].esquerda = 5;
    arvore[2].direita = 6;
    
    arvore[3].dado = '0';
    arvore[3].pai = 1;
    arvore[3].esquerda = 7;
    arvore[3].direita = 8;
    
    arvore[5].dado = '3';
    arvore[5].pai = 3;
    arvore[5].esquerda = 11;
    arvore[5].direita = 12;
    
    arvore[8].dado = '0';
    arvore[8].pai = 3;
    arvore[8].esquerda = 17;
    arvore[8].direita = 18;
    
    arvore[11].dado = '2';
    arvore[11].pai = 5;
    arvore[11].esquerda = 23;
    arvore[11].direita = 24;
    
    arvore[12].dado = '5';
    arvore[12].pai = 5;
    arvore[12].esquerda = 25;
    arvore[12].direita = 26;
    
    arvore[24].dado = '2';
    arvore[24].pai = 11;
    arvore[24].esquerda = -1;
    arvore[24].direita = -1;
    
    printf("Arvore binaria de busca ordenada: \n");
    for (int i = 0; i <= 24; i++){
        printf("| %c ",arvore[i].dado);
    }
    
    printf("\nBusca pre ordem: \n");
    preOrdem(arvore);
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A sua função `preOrdem` pede um parâmetro do tipo `str_no*`. No entanto, na própria função você está passando `raiz->esquerda` e `raiz->direita` como argumentos, sendo que estes valores são inteiros. Você pode modificar sua função para pedir o ponteiro da árvore e o índice do elemento a ser consultado ou transformar esta árvore numa estrutura encadeada, mudando os campos `esquerda` e `direita` para ponteiros deste mesmo tipo.